# ヒープの深さと各深さにおける要素数から和を求めるプログラムのエラー

Tags: python, python3, アルゴリズム, データ構造

前回の質問
[要素数nのヒープの深さと各深さにおける要素数を求める方法について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/55894/%e8%a6%81%e7%b4%a0%e6%95%b0n%e3%81%ae%e3%83%92%e3%83%bc%e3%83%97%e3%81%ae%e6%b7%b1%e3%81%95%e3%81%a8%e5%90%84%e6%b7%b1%e3%81%95%e3%81%ab%e3%81%8a%e3%81%91%e3%82%8b%e8%a6%81%e7%b4%a0%e6%95%b0%e3%82%92%e6%b1%82%e3%82%81%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6)
でいただいたコメントを参考に以下のプログラムを書き、実行しましたがエラーが出ています。

エラー

```
$ python sample.py
depth_list
[0, 1, 2, 3]
element
[1, 2, 4, 1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 23, in <module>
    total += depth[j]*element[j]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

どのように修正すれば良いでしょうか。

実行プログラム

```
import heapq
import math
a = [6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 1, 8]
heapq.heapify(a)

num = int(math.log2(len(a)))

depth_list = []
for i in range(num+1):
    depth_list.append(i)

print('depth_list')
print(depth_list)


depth = int(math.log2(len(a)))
element= [2**x for x in range(depth)] + [len(a) - (2**depth - 1)]
print('element')
print(element)

total = 0
for j in range (len(depth_list)):
    total += depth[j]*element[j]
    # 0*1 + 1*2 + 2*4 + 3*1

print('tolal')
print(total)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

変数 `depth` はリストでなくて整数なので、`depth[j]` のように添え字をつけることはできないため生じているエラーです。

Comment: ご回答いただきましてありがとうございます。
補足として、今回のプログラムの計算量をヒープを構成する要素数len(a)=nとしてオーダで考えるとO(log2(n))という理解でしょうか。2**x for x in range(num)もfor j in range (len(depth_list))も繰り返し回数はlog2(n)+1なので、オーダ記法だと全体としてO(log2(n))に抑えられると考えましたが、ご意見を伺いたいです。
別質問にした方が良い場合はご指摘ください。

Comment: そもそも現在質問文に書かれているプログラムは実行時エラーが出るので時間計算量を見積もる以前の問題です。

Comment: 「ご回答を受けて冗長な部分があったため修正」の下に明記したプログラムはこちらの環境では実行可能ですが、そちらではエラーが出てしまうのでしょうか。

Comment: そうなると、ご自身が書かれているように質問内容が異なるので、別質問の方が良さそうです。コメント欄は狭くてQ&Aをするには向いていません。

Comment: 質問させていただきました。よろしくお願いいたします。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/55989/%e3%83%92%e3%83%bc%e3%83%97%e3%81%ae%e6%b7%b1%e3%81%95%e3%81%a8%e5%90%84%e6%b7%b1%e3%81%95%e3%81%ab%e3%81%8a%e3%81%91%e3%82%8b%e8%a6%81%e7%b4%a0%e6%95%b0%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e5%92%8c%e3%82%92%e6%b1%82%e3%82%81%e3%82%8b%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b0%e3%83%a9%e3%83%a0%e3%81%ae%e6%99%82%e9%96%93%e8%a8%88%e7%ae%97%e9%87%8f