# ヒープの深さと各深さにおける要素数から和を求めるプログラムの時間計算量

Tags: python, python3, アルゴリズム, 計算量

今回書いたプログラムの計算量をヒープを構成する要素数`len(a)` *=n* としてオーダで考えると *O(log2(n))* という理解でしょうか。

`2**x for x in range(num)`も`for j in range (len(depth_list))`も繰り返し回数は *log2(n)+1* なので、オーダ記法だと全体として *O(log2(n))* に抑えられると考えましたが、計算量を見積もるのにまだ不慣れなため、ご意見を伺いたいです。

該当プログラム

```
import heapq
import math
a = [6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 1, 8]
heapq.heapify(a)

num = int(math.log2(len(a)))

depth_list = []
for i in range(num+1):
    depth_list.append(i)

print('depth_list')
print(depth_list)


element= [2**x for x in range(num)] + [len(a) - (2**num - 1)]
print('element')
print(element)

total = 0
for j in range (len(depth_list)):
    total += depth_list[j]*element[j]

print('tolal')
print(total)
```

Comment: 掲示されているコードの `for j in range (len(depth_list)): total += depth_list[j]*element[j]` の部分ですが、`depth_list` はつまるところ `element` のインデックスですので(かつ、`depth_list` と `element` の長さ(要素数)は同じ)、`for i, v in enumerate(element): total += i * v` と書くこともできます(`depth_list` は不要になります)。

Comment: @metropolis コメントいただきましてありがとうございます。必要メモリと実行行が減るので計算量の削減にはなりますが、オーダ記法には影響しないですよね。

Comment: はい、影響はありません。ところで、計算内容は `Σ(k*(2**k)){k=1〜depth-1} +  depth * element[depth]` なので、`Σ(k*(2**k)){k:[1, depth-1]}` の部分を予め計算しておく方法もあろうかと思います。例えば depth が 10 までなら `sums = [0, 2, 10, 34, 98, 258, 642, 1538, 3586, 8194, 18484]` になります。この場合、計算量は `O(1)` になります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず最初に、Big-O表記では定数倍の違いは無視するので、`O(log2(n))`という書き方はしません。`O(log(n))`か、数学の式に近い書き方で`O(log n)`ですね。

ループ絡みの計算量は、

`ループの実行回数 ×`**`ループ1回あたりの計算量`**

となります。

「繰り返し回数は *log2(n)+1* なので、オーダ記法だと全体として *O(log2(n))*」が成立するためには、

#### 「ループ1回あたりの計算量」が`O(1)`であること

が条件となります。意図せず`O(1)`より計算量の多いメソッド等を使用していないかも注意すべきです。

というわけでループしているところを順番にチェック。

---

```
for i in range(num+1):    #<-実行回数: num+1
    depth_list.append(i)  #<-時間計算量: O(1) ... ?
```

リスト操作は呼び出し1回が`O(N)`になるものが多数あるので要注意です。`append`の場合でいうと、内部領域が不足したときに、領域を拡張する操作は`O(N)`なんですが、そのような拡張は`1/N`の確率でしか発生しないように調整されているので、平均では`O(1)`と考えて良いです。

`append`ではなく、`insert`を使用すると話が変わってくる場合もありますので、要注意。

---

```
element= [2**x for x in range(num)] + [len(a) - (2**num - 1)]
```

ご質問中では無視されているようですが、リスト内包表記も入力のシーケンス長`N`に対して`N`回ループします。1回のループ内では`2**x`の計算を行いますが、これは`O(1)`操作と考えて良い(*1)でしょう。よってここも全体では`O(log(n))`ですね。

*1 値により計算量が変化する可能性もあるんですが、上限もあるので無視しておきます。

---

で、最後のループ:

```
for j in range (len(depth_list)):
    total += depth_list[j]*element[j] #<- O(1) ... ?
```

ループ内の処理では

- リストの要素参照(`[]`)
- 数値型の掛け算(`*`)
- 数値型の累積加算(`+=`)

などが行われていますが、どれも`O(1)`と考えて良いでしょう。よって、ループ全体の計算量は`O(log(n))`ということになります。

---

と言うわけでどのループも同じオーダーで処理ができるので、全体としても同じオーダーで

#### `O(log(n))`は正解

と言ってしまって良いと思います。

(私的には、ご質問中の`total`って、何を計算しているのかよくわからないのですが…。)

---

計算量の評価の際には`O(1)`ではない操作(以前出てきた`sum`, `sort`など)を正しく評価してやる必要があります。リスト用の関数など呼ぶ場合には特に気をつけないといけません。

Comment: ご回答いただきましてありがとうございます。totalは、深さx要素数を計算して足し込んでいって、和を求める計算です。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。「何を計算しているのか」と言うのは、「何に使われるものなのか」と言う意味です。アルゴリズムの話にちょくちょく首を突っ込んでいながら、その辺の統計量にどう言う意味があるのかがまるでわかっていないので、ちょっと疑問に思ったものです。

Comment: アルゴリズムを適用させる問題に寄るかと思います。今回の場合、単純にプログラミングの勉強のために計算しました。